# Storing List of custom type in Win Forms application settings

Tags: c#, winforms, application-settings, collectioneditor

I am trying to store a `List` of a custom type in application settings and have been unable to get the collection editor working properly. My class appears in the settings Type dropdown, but when I go to enter a value, there is an arrow that opens a box to edit the plain text value instead of "..." to open the Collection editor. I did the same thing as [this person](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/753679-problems-storing-custom-type-application-settings#post3019412), but either something changed since the version of Visual Studio he used, or I did something slightly different.

Comment: Every once in a while, it will work fine, but the next time I build, it stops working

Comment: It seems to work when I restart Visual Studio with the settings page closed, but it stops working after the next build